# windows 10 flickers screen and then system shut downs

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, shutdown, safe-mode

OK here is the situation on my laptop. I have **windows 10 1607** ( anniversary update) installed after f**ormatting my whole hard disk** and when I install new window then PC remains logged in for about **40 minutes** and then suddenly screen starts to flicker and after **flickering of 10- 20 seconds** my pc suddenly crashes and **shutdowns** completely immediately.
When I turn it on again, the window logs in normally and this time the same thing happens but it doesnt stay normal for 40 minutes but actually for about 30 seconds after logging in it crashes again.

*I have tried re installing windows multiple times. so a fresh install gives me 40 normal minutes and apart from that it gives me 30 seconds and then it crashes in all cases.*

Previously I had **windows fall creators update ( insiders build )** and this problem started to occur and I thought it is bug in insiders build so I formatted my pc and did installation of **anniversary update (1607 )**. but as I told you above problem is occuring in this version as well.

**NOTE** : If I restart and log in windows in **safe mode** then windows stays logged in and it never crashes. So maybe some windows own applicatin is causing the crash. But how do I fix this? and how can I know which application of windows is causing the trouble?

**UPDATE**:  I currently have ubuntu 14 installed on my laptop and it is working perfectly and never shuts down.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you looked in the event logs for anything relevant?

Comment: where can I find that?

Comment: [Using Event Viewer to Troubleshoot Problems](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/)

Comment: isnt event viewer a gui app on windows? so how can I troubleshoot, when my pc actually crashes?

Comment: Safe mode will run GUI apps so you can look at the event logs for events at the last shutdown time.

Comment: I am tryng but event viewer isnt opening

Comment: I am able to open it now but it doesn't show anything relevant @DavidPostill